# MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra in .Net framework

Tags: c#, .net, matrix

How can I instantiate a matrix and perform some matrix operations? 
Example if I want to perform matrix multiplication between;

A = [[ 1  2 ][ 3  4 ]]

B = [[ 2  4 ][ 6  8 ]]

C=A*B

I only need a simple sample code using the namespace "MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra" to instantiate and perform the above operation.

Comment: What part are you stuck on?  Also - why C# and F#?

Comment: I really have no any basic idea how it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DenseMatrix class has a factory method that takes a 2-dimensional array (of double).
So you can do this:

`DenseMatrix A = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] { {1, 2}, {3, 4} });`
`DenseMatrix A = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] { {2, 4}, {6, 8} });`

Then just multiply them:

```
DenseMatrix C = A * B;
```

Is this what you needed?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I needed. Please would you help with how to compute Inverse of matrix A for example?

Comment: I think the namespace MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.Factorization has a class UserLU that has a method called Inverse. Maybe you should read more before asking? ;)